# Extracting XMP metadata from EPS files

Tags: c#, asp-classic, eps, xmp

I am trying to implement a module in either C# or classic ASP, which extracts the XMP data from a EPS file.

Is there a framework or component (not necesarilly free) which can help me to create this module?

Any advice / direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't check http://www.imagemagick.org/ should be able to do this and it can be loaded as an ASP COM object.

```
' example usage in ASP - resize an image
Set img = CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1")
msgs = img.convert(src, "-scale", "200x200", trg)
```

Edit:

According to this info it is possible:

[How to get EXIF keywords using mini_magick in a Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960551/how-to-get-exif-keywords-using-mini-magick-in-a-rails-app)

Re-written for this new info (not tested):

```
Set img = CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1")
msgs = img.convert("identify", "-verbose", trg)
```

Where trg is your file, you would then have to process the output to get the info you needed.